# show page number I choose on table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, books

I'm using the *book* class.
In the begining of my document, I've used `\frontmatter` in order to switch page numbering to Roman numerals and `\mainmatter` to end this up and returning to Arabic numerals.

Why the page numbers of all *'addcontentsline{toc} {chapter} {my_CONTENT}'* between the block `\frontmatter` … `\mainmatter` aren't shown in table of contents?

What must I do to get these page numbers in Roman numerals on my table of contents?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As a general recommendation, try to avoid the addcontentsline but use proper chapter commands. Why do need the addcontentsline?